# Twitter confirm email will not work for me

Tags: twitter

I created an account for Twitter.
I got a Confirm email dialog.
I got the email and I confirmed.
I have now been through the resend confirm email cycle more than 100 times, and I have reached out to Twitter numerous times, probably more than 30 and every time, I get a Password Reset from them and go through the email confirm cycle and it never ends.
All the time i have this yellow dialog at the top of the screen that says to Confirm Me email.

I have tried to figure out how to contact twitter to figure out how to fix the problem but I feel like such a twit, I cannot seem to get through.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Help Center](https://support.twitter.com/articles/82050):

**I'm having trouble confirming my email address**

> [Nothing is working. Help!](https://support.twitter.com/articles/82050#nothing-works)
>
> If you’ve tried resending the email and you are still having trouble, here are some troubleshooting tips:
>
> 1. Are we sending it to the wrong email address? Double check your [Account settings](https://twitter.com/settings/account) to make sure your email is entered accurately. See any typos? Do we have an old email on file? Make any necessary corrections and click save; we’ll send another email if you’ve updated the address.
> 2. Try changing the email address to an email address with a large domain (Gmail, Yahoo, etc.). We tend to have more success delivering emails to those types of domains.
> 3. Still need help? Contact us [here](https://support.twitter.com/forms/signin).

Just for try you can just change your email and try to verify new email address.